# How to insert picture into TRichEdit in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I searched over internet for how to inserting picture in `RichEdit`. I only found inserting `TImage` into Richedit, or other 3rd part components to do it for me. I don't want to use other components or insert `TImage` into RichEdit.

Is there any other way to do this?

I want to insert it in line so I can use paragraph actions like justify on it (inserting `TImage` does not provide this as i found in examples and tested, am i wrong?). I want to write something like what happened in `TJVRichEdit` (in JVCL package) re-sizing picture in Richedit can be ignored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can wrap your image inside of an [`IOleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542709.aspx) interface, such as via the [`OleCreateFromData()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691211.aspx) or [`OleCreateFromFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690116.aspx) function, then you can use the [`EM_GETOLEINTERFACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb788041.aspx) message to retreive an [`IRichEditOle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774306.aspx) interface from the `TRichEdit`  and then call its `InsertObject()` method to insert the actual image.  The tricky part is wrapping the image inside of an [`IOleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542709.aspx) to begin with, but it can be done with some work.

**Update:** here is a rough translation of the information provided by MSDN in the following article:

[How to insert a bitmap into an RTF document using the RichEdit control in Visual C++ 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220844)

```
uses
  ..., Winapi.ActiveX, RichOle;

var
  RichEditOle: IRichEditOle;
  LockBytes: ILockBytes;
  ClientSite: IOleClientSite;
  Storage: IStorage;
  Image: IOleObject;
  Obj: REOBJECT;
  Fmt: FORMATETC;
begin
  if RichEdit_GetOleInterface(RichEdit1.Handle, RichEditOle) then
  begin
    ZeroMemory(@Fmt, SizeOf(Fmt));
    Fmt.cfFormat := 0;
    Fmt.ptd := nil;
    Fmt.dwAspect := DVASPECT_CONTENT;
    Fmt.lindex := -1;
    Fmt.tymed := TYMED_NULL;

    OleCheck(CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal(nil, True, LockBytes));
    OleCheck(StgCreateDocfileOnILockBytes(LockBytes, STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE or STGM_CREATE or STGM_READWRITE, 0, Storage));
    OleCheck(RichEditOle.GetClientSite(ClientSite));
    OleCheck(OleCreateFromFile(CLSID_NULL, PChar(FileName), IOleObject, OLERENDER_DRAW, @Fmt, ClientSite, Storage, Image));
    OleSetContainedObject(Image, True);

    ZeroMemory(@Obj, sizeof(Obj));
    Obj.cbStruct := SizeOf(Obj);
    Obj.cp := REO_CP_SELECTION;
    OleCheck(Image.GetUserClassID(Obj.clsid));
    Obj.poleobj := Image;
    Obj.pstg := Storage;
    Obj.polesite := ClientSite;
    Obj.sizel.cx := 0;
    Obj.sizel.cx := 0;
    Obj.dvaspect := DVASPECT_CONTENT;
    Obj.dwFlags := 0;
    Obj.dwUser := 0;

    OleCheck(RichEditOle.InsertObject(Obj));
  end;
end;
```

And here is a third-party version of the `RichOle` unit (which Embarcadero does not provide a version of):

```
{
  RichOle.pas

  Pascal version of richole.h (version: 2005 platform SDK).

  Version 1.3d - always find the most current version at
  http://flocke.vssd.de/prog/code/pascal/rtflabel/

  Copyright (C) 2001-2009 Volker Siebert <flocke@vssd.de>
  All rights reserved.

  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a
  copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"),
  to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation
  the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense,
  and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
  Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
  all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
  IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
  AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
  LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
  FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
  DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
}

{$I DelphiVersion.inc}

{$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}
{$HPPEMIT '#include <RichOle.h>'}
{$ENDIF}

unit RichOle;

{$WEAKPACKAGEUNIT}
{$MINENUMSIZE 4}

interface

uses
  Windows, ActiveX, RichEdit;

(*
 *      RICHOLE.H
 *
 *      Purpose:
 *              OLE Extensions to the Rich Text Editor
 *
 *      Copyright (c) 1985-1999, Microsoft Corporation
 *)

// Structure passed to GetObject and InsertObject
type
  PReObject = ^TReObject;
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM _REOBJECT}{$ENDIF}
  _REOBJECT = packed record
    cbStruct: DWORD;            // [00] Size of structure
    cp: LongInt;                // [04] Character position of object
    clsid: TCLSID;              // [08] Class ID of object
    oleobj: IOleObject;         // [18] OLE object interface
    stg: IStorage;              // [1C] Associated storage interface
    olesite: IOLEClientSite;    // [20] Associated client site interface
    sizel: TSize;               // [24] Size of object (may be 0,0)
    dvaspect: DWORD;            // [2C] Display aspect to use
    dwFlags: DWORD;             // [30] Object status flags
    dwUser: DWORD;              // [34] Dword for user's use
  end;
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REOBJECT}{$ENDIF}
  REOBJECT = _reobject;
  TReObject = _reobject;

const
  // Flags to specify which interfaces should
  // be returned in the structure above
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_GETOBJ_NO_INTERFACES}{$ENDIF}
  REO_GETOBJ_NO_INTERFACES  = $00000000;
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_GETOBJ_POLEOBJ}{$ENDIF}
  REO_GETOBJ_POLEOBJ        = $00000001;
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_GETOBJ_PSTG}{$ENDIF}
  REO_GETOBJ_PSTG           = $00000002;
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_GETOBJ_POLESITE}{$ENDIF}
  REO_GETOBJ_POLESITE       = $00000004;
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_GETOBJ_ALL_INTERFACES}{$ENDIF}
  REO_GETOBJ_ALL_INTERFACES = $00000007;

  // Place object at selection
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_CP_SELECTION}{$ENDIF}
  REO_CP_SELECTION          = -1;  // why? cardinal(-1);

  // Use character position to specify object instead of index
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_IOB_SELECTION}{$ENDIF}
  REO_IOB_SELECTION         = -1;  // why? cardinal(-1);
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_IOB_USE_CP}{$ENDIF}
  REO_IOB_USE_CP            = -2;  // why? cardinal(-2);

  // Object flags
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_NULL}{$ENDIF}
  REO_NULL                  = $00000000;  // No flags
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_READWRITEMASK}{$ENDIF}
  REO_READWRITEMASK         = $0000003F;  // Mask out RO bits
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_DONTNEEDPALETTE}{$ENDIF}
  REO_DONTNEEDPALETTE       = $00000020;  // Object doesn't need palette
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_BLANK}{$ENDIF}
  REO_BLANK                 = $00000010;  // Object is blank
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_DYNAMICSIZE}{$ENDIF}
  REO_DYNAMICSIZE           = $00000008;  // Object defines size always
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_INVERTEDSELECT}{$ENDIF}
  REO_INVERTEDSELECT        = $00000004;  // Object drawn all inverted if sel
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_BELOWBASELINE}{$ENDIF}
  REO_BELOWBASELINE         = $00000002;  // Object sits below the baseline
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_RESIZABLE}{$ENDIF}
  REO_RESIZABLE             = $00000001;  // Object may be resized
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_LINK}{$ENDIF}
  REO_LINK                  = $80000000;  // Object is a link (RO)
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_STATIC}{$ENDIF}
  REO_STATIC                = $40000000;  // Object is static (RO)
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_SELECTED}{$ENDIF}
  REO_SELECTED              = $08000000;  // Object selected (RO)
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_OPEN}{$ENDIF}
  REO_OPEN                  = $04000000;  // Object open in its server (RO)
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_INPLACEACTIVE}{$ENDIF}
  REO_INPLACEACTIVE         = $02000000;  // Object in place active (RO)
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_HILITED}{$ENDIF}
  REO_HILITED               = $01000000;  // Object is to be hilited (RO)
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_LINKAVAILABLE}{$ENDIF}
  REO_LINKAVAILABLE         = $00800000;  // Link believed available (RO)
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM REO_GETMETAFILE}{$ENDIF}
  REO_GETMETAFILE           = $00400000;  // Object requires metafile (RO)

  // flags for IRichEditOle::GetClipboardData(),
  // IRichEditOleCallback::GetClipboardData() and
  // IRichEditOleCallback::QueryAcceptData()
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM RECO_PASTE}{$ENDIF}
  RECO_PASTE                = $00000000;  // paste from clipboard
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM RECO_DROP}{$ENDIF}
  RECO_DROP                 = $00000001;  // drop
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM RECO_COPY}{$ENDIF}
  RECO_COPY                 = $00000002;  // copy to the clipboard
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM RECO_CUT}{$ENDIF}
  RECO_CUT                  = $00000003;  // cut to the clipboard
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM RECO_DRAG}{$ENDIF}
  RECO_DRAG                 = $00000004;  // drag

type
  (*
   * IRichEditOle
   *
   * Purpose:
   *   Interface used by the client of RichEdit to perform OLE-related
   *   operations.
   *
   * //$ REVIEW:
   *   The methods herein may just want to be regular Windows messages.
   *)
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM IRichEditOle}{$ENDIF}
  IRichEditOle = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{00020D00-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}']
    // *** IRichEditOle methods ***
    function GetClientSite(out clientSite: IOleClientSite): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetObjectCount: LongInt; stdcall;
    function GetLinkCount: LongInt; stdcall;
    function GetObject(iob: LongInt; out ReObject: TReObject;
      dwFlags: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InsertObject(var ReObject: TReObject): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ConvertObject(iob: LongInt; const clsidNew: TCLSID;
      lpStrUserTypeNew: LPCSTR): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ActivateAs(const clsid, clsidAs: TCLSID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetHostNames(lpstrContainerApp: LPCSTR;
      lpstrContainerObj: LPCSTR): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetLinkAvailable(iob: LongInt; fAvailable: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetDvaspect(iob: LongInt; dvaspect: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function HandsOffStorage(iob: LongInt): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SaveCompleted(iob: LongInt; const stg: IStorage): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InPlaceDeactivate: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ContextSensitiveHelp(fEnterMode: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetClipboardData(const chrg: TCharRange; reco: DWORD;
      out dataobj: IDataObject): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ImportDataObject(const dataobj: IDataObject; cf: TClipFormat;
      hMetaPict: HGLOBAL): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  (*
   * IRichEditOleCallback
   *
   * Purpose:
   *   Interface used by the RichEdit to get OLE-related stuff from the
   *   application using RichEdit.
   *)
  {$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM IRichEditOleCallback}{$ENDIF}
  IRichEditOleCallback = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{00020D03-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}']
    // *** IRichEditOleCallback methods ***
    function GetNewStorage(out stg: IStorage): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetInPlaceContext(out Frame: IOleInPlaceFrame;
      out Doc: IOleInPlaceUIWindow;
      lpFrameInfo: POleInPlaceFrameInfo): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ShowContainerUI(fShow: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function QueryInsertObject(const clsid: TCLSID; const stg: IStorage;
      cp: LongInt): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function DeleteObject(const oleobj: IOleObject): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function QueryAcceptData(const dataobj: IDataObject;
      var cfFormat: TClipFormat; reco: DWORD; fReally: BOOL;
      hMetaPict: HGLOBAL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ContextSensitiveHelp(fEnterMode: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetClipboardData(const chrg: TCharRange; reco: DWORD;
      out dataobj: IDataObject): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDragDropEffect(fDrag: BOOL; grfKeyState: DWORD;
      var dwEffect: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetContextMenu(seltype: Word; oleobj: IOleObject;
      const chrg: TCharRange; var menu: HMENU): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

const
  IID_IRichEditOle: TGUID = '{00020D00-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}';
  IID_IRichEditOleCallback: TGUID = '{00020D03-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}';

{$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM RichEdit_SetOleCallback}{$ENDIF}
function RichEdit_SetOleCallback(Wnd: HWND;
  const Intf: IRichEditOleCallback): Boolean;
{$IFDEF CPPBUILDER}{$EXTERNALSYM RichEdit_GetOleInterface}{$ENDIF}
function RichEdit_GetOleInterface(Wnd: HWND; out Intf: IRichEditOle): Boolean;

implementation

function RichEdit_SetOleCallback(Wnd: HWND;
  const Intf: IRichEditOleCallback): Boolean;
begin
  Result := SendMessage(Wnd, EM_SETOLECALLBACK, 0, LongInt(Intf)) <> 0;
end;

function RichEdit_GetOleInterface(Wnd: HWND; out Intf: IRichEditOle): Boolean;
begin
  Result := SendMessage(Wnd, EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, 0, LongInt(@Intf)) <> 0;
end;

end.
```

Comment: If you have done it, a little code sample would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The code below (based on Remy's code - this is basically an update of his code) will insert a bmp as an Object into the RTF document.
I will try to provide code that can insert the bmp as an actual inline-image.

```
uses 
  RichOle, System.Win.ComObj,

procedure InsertImageToRTF(Editor: TRichEdit; FileName: string);
var
  RichEditOle: IRichEditOle;
  LockBytes: ILockBytes;
  ClientSite: IOleClientSite;
  Storage: IStorage;
  Image: IOleObject;
  Obj: REOBJECT;
  Fmt: FORMATETC;
  Global: HGLOBAL;
  ClassID: TGUID;  
begin
  if RichEdit_GetOleInterface(Editor.Handle, RichEditOle) then
  begin
    ZeroMemory(@Fmt, SizeOf(Fmt));
    Fmt.cfFormat := 0;
    Fmt.ptd := nil;
    Fmt.dwAspect := DVASPECT_CONTENT;
    Fmt.lindex := -1;
    Fmt.tymed := TYMED_NULL;

    // Allocate a global memory handle
    Global := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE or GMEM_ZEROINIT, 0);
    if Global = 0 then
      RaiseLastOSError;

    // Create ILockBytes interface on the global memory handle
    OleCheck(CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal(Global, True, LockBytes));

    OleCheck(StgCreateDocfileOnILockBytes(LockBytes, STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE or STGM_CREATE or STGM_READWRITE, 0, Storage));
    OleCheck(RichEditOle.GetClientSite(ClientSite));

    // Use the class ID for a generic embedded object
    ClassID := CLSID_StdPicture;
    OleCheck(OleCreateFromFile(ClassID, PChar(FileName), IOleObject, OLERENDER_DRAW, @Fmt, ClientSite, Storage, Image));
    OleSetContainedObject(Image, True);

    ZeroMemory(@Obj, SizeOf(Obj));
    Obj.cbStruct := SizeOf(Obj);
    Obj.cp := REO_CP_SELECTION;
    OleCheck(Image.GetUserClassID(Obj.clsid));
    Obj.oleobj := Image;
    Obj.stg := Storage;
    Obj.olesite := ClientSite;
    Obj.sizel.cx := 0;
    Obj.sizel.cx := 0;
    Obj.dvaspect := DVASPECT_CONTENT;
    Obj.dwFlags := 0;
    Obj.dwUser := 0;

    OleCheck(RichEditOle.InsertObject(Obj));

    // Release the global memory handle
    GlobalFree(Global);
  end;
end;


//Tested on Delphi 10.4 
procedure TMainForm.Test(Sender: TObject);
begin
 InsertImageToRTF(Editor, 'bmp.bmp');
end;
```

PS: the article mentioned by Remy is not anymore online but you can find a copy here:
https://ftp.zx.net.nz/pub/archive/ftp.microsoft.com/MISC/KB/en-us/220/844.HTM

Comment: PS: this library has support for inserting images into rtfs http://www.micrel.cz/RxLib/dfiles.htm 
Ant it is free.

Answer (score 0):

I used a mix of TJVRichEdit and OLE, assigned Word Document 97-2003 to my OLEContainer, after editing in Word environment save it as RTF:

```
OLEContainer.OLEObject.SaveAs(Save_Path, $00000006);
```

and then load it into JVRichEdit, works well!

Comment: can someone tell how to close word document in OLEContainer and make a new document? "OLEContainer.Close" will close only Word environment and show its content in OLEContainer, by double click on it last session will continue, how to make a new one?

Comment: i couldnt find any reference to show how work with MS Word (or any other opened application inside OLEContainer), but finally find how to close opened word document in OLEContainer: 

    `If Not (OLEContainer.State = osEmpty) Then  
        OLEContainer.Close;  
        OLEContainer.CreateObject('Word.Document', False);`  

Thanks to Peter Below

Answer (score -1):

You want TRichedit to be TWordEdit which it isn't.

Out of the box TRichedit doesn't support inline images. You either have to implement it yourself, get a cutom Richedit component (like RxRichedit I think) or start thinking about ole automation and load it as a word document.

Comment: `TRichEdit` out of the box CAN display inline images, via the [`IRichEditOle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774306.aspx) interface.